# Trying to extract meta data from news article

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the meta tags from a cnn article

```
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request(http://www.cnn.com/2016/08/09/health/chagas-sleeping-sickness-leishmaniasis-drug/index.html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
print(soup.select('body > div.pg-right-rail-tall.pg-wrapper.pg__background__image > article > meta'))
```

I am trying to narrow it down to just this output

```
<meta content="health" itemprop="articleSection"><meta content="2016-08-09T12:10:24Z" itemprop="dateCreated"><meta content="2016-08-09T12:10:24Z" itemprop="datePublished"><meta content="2016-08-09T12:10:24Z" itemprop="dateModified"><meta content="http://www.cnn.com/2016/08/09/health/chagas-sleeping-sickness-leishmaniasis-drug/index.html" itemprop="url"><meta content="Meera Senthilingam, for CNN" itemprop="author"><meta content="Could one discovery take on three deadly parasites?  - CNN.com" itemprop="headline"><meta content="Three seemingly different diseases infect 20 million people each year: Chagas disease, leishmaniasis and African sleeping sickness. But one drug could be developed to fight all three." itemprop="description"><meta content="sleeping sickness, disease, drug, drug development, chagas disease, leishmaniasis, Novartis, health, Could one discovery take on three deadly parasites?  - CNN.com" itemprop="keywords"><meta content="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150812101743-chagas-bug-large-tease.jpg" itemprop="image"><meta content="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150812101743-chagas-bug-large-tease.jpg" itemprop="thumbnailUrl"><meta content="Could one discovery take on three deadly parasites? " itemprop="alternativeHeadline">
```

but for some reason the `BeautifulSoup.select()` method is returning about 100x as much of the html as I want.  I would really appreciate any advice on how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the parser/html that is the issue, *lxml* and *html5lib* gives you what you want.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")
```

Or:

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"html5lib")
```

If you don't have with *lxml* or *html5lib* installed, you can install *html5lib* using pip, *lxml* is a bit more involved depending on your OS as it has a few dependencies but it is definitely worth installing.

You can also simplify your select:

```
soup.select('div.pg-right-rail-tall.pg-wrapper.pg__background__image meta')
```